# If I have a list of things, how do I associate a item to those things? Python

Tags: python

So I have an assignment that is due later tonight and I'm stuck on this one definition. What I have is a list of random terms:

```
['i', 'am', 'a', 'brown', 'cow']
```

And what I want to do with this list is associate each term to a value/term:

```
[['i', ['term']], ['am', ['term']], ['a', ['term']], ['brown', ['term']], ['cow', ['term']]]
```

My thoughts on how to get started on this was to use a for loop and append the term after each key term and somehow try to separate each pair.

Comment: The simplest way to go really is a for loop appending things to a list. Why didn't that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a beginner in Python, the most obvious option probably would be simple loop approach:

```
d = {}
lst = ['i', 'am', 'a', 'brown', 'cow']
for key in lst:
  d[key] = 'term'
```

After this you can access your elements like this:

```
In:  print d['am']
Out: 'term'
```

Of course, this is not the best way to do this. As other have already said, you should take a look at [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and builtin [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function. I will try to write some examples of code using list comprehension and `zip()` function, but it is still highly recommended to read the official documentation.

You should note that list comprehension always gives you a list as a result, so the best thing you can get is what you have demonstrated in your question. Here is a small example:

```
lst = ['i', 'am', 'a', 'brown', 'cow']
res = [[item, ['term']] for item in lst]
```

This will give you exactly the same you have written in your question. In case you want to get a dict (as in our first example), you might want to modify this code slightly:

```
lst = ['i', 'am', 'a', 'brown', 'cow']
res = [(item, 'term') for item in lst]
d = dict(res)
```

And again you have:

```
In : print d['am']
Out: 'term'
```

Now, you probably want to assign different terms to different elements of your list.
Let's say you have two lists of the same length, one with elements, the other with terms:

```
lst = ['i', 'am', 'a', 'brown', 'cow']
terms = ['term1', 'term2', 'term3', 'term4', 'term5']
```

This is where `zip()` function helps. If you pass it `lst` and `terms` as arguments, it will give you a list of tuples (just as in our `res` variable a few lines before):

```
In : zip(lst, terms)
Out: [('i', 'term1'), ('am', 'term2'), ('a', 'term3'), ('brown', 'term4'), ('cow', 'term5')]
```

And now you can again use `dict` to create a new dictionary:

```
what_i_need = dict(zip(lst, terms))
```

Comment: Ooohh thanks a lot for the help! I didn't know you could assign terms like that in for loops. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to help you :) If you consider my answer helpful, you can upvote or/and accept it ;)

Comment: For some reason I get a return value of none when I try this:

old_ial = ial.append([[token, [image]] for token in words_separated])

When I go through the debugger, it shows the items being appended to the ial, but then right after the last item is appended, I get a return value of None. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, `ial.append(smth)` will append `smth` as an element of `ial`, not concatenate two lists. Second, `ial.append(smth)` modifies `ial` and returns `None` always. `.append()` method is not intended to return some value, it modifies it's owner. If you want to create a new list as a concatenation of two others, you may just use `+` sign like this: `new_list = [1,2,3] + [4,5,6]`

Comment: @JasonD, append modifies `ial`, but it always returns `None`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at pythons [zip() function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

Also [python list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) may come handy sometimes in these kind of problems.